# How to use one ssl certificate for different ports on nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, port

I am trying to configure my nginx to support ssl for different ports. If i do it for port 3000 where my react app is running then only that becomes https which means it doesnot allow port 5000 requests to pass through as 5000 is still http. I am using aws ec2. Below is my code for nginx default file.
`enter code here`

```js
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name merkle.org www.merkle.org;
       return 301 https://merkle.org$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen 443 ssl;
server_name merkle.org web.merkle.org;
       # Certificate
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/merkle_org.crt;

       # Private Key
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
        location / {
        # My react 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

        location /5000{
        # This is my nodejs API 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }



}
```

Comment: The `location /5000` block causes an incoming request `https://merkle.org/5000` to be routed to `http://localhost:5000/5000` which probably isn't what you want. `location /api` would be a reasonable choice I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to configure my nginx to support ssl for different ports

I assume you actually want to support SSL on a *single* port (the default, 443) for different backend ports, correct?

In this case you first need to think of a way to clearly distinguish incoming requests. There are (at least) two popular approaches here:

1. Have a separate (sub)domain for the API, e.g. `api.example.com`
2. Route by URL path, e.g. `/api`

Note that for the first approach you'd need a separate certificate (or a single certificate that includes this name).